INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Disconnecting from node 0 due to socket connection setup timeout
I am running my Kafka and Zookeeper on EC2, this is my ZK properties:
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper

# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181

# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0

# Disable the adminserver by default to avoid port conflicts.
# Set the port to something non-conflicting if choosing to enable this

admin.enableServer=false

# admin.serverPort=8080

and this is my Kafka properties:
############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. If not configured, the host name will be equal to the value of
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName(), with PLAINTEXT listener name, and port 9092.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092

# Listener name, hostname and port the broker will advertise to clients.
# If not set, it uses the value for "listeners".
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://34.202.229.148:9092
# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more d$
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################

# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "\__consumer_offsets" and "\__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of d$
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive se$
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.
# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of d$
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive se$
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.
# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever \*either\* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.
# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
#log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

I ran bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties to start my ZK and bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties to run the broker
| –sgr-04f7ec448d6bff0ee | IPv4 | SSH | TCP | 22 | 0.0.0.0/0 | – |
| –sgr-040de62a43bed1efa | IPv4 | All traffic | All | All | \<my local IP\> | allow our local computer acess ec2 |

above is my inbound rules
I don't understand why I kept getting this error.

listeners cannot be 127.0.0.1 if you plan on allowing external connections... Otherwise, you could setup MSK rather than using EC2. You also shouldn't store any important data under /tmp

I set it to 0.0.0.0 and it didnt work
